# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected time_distributed_46_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (200, 200, 3)

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am tinkering with the the Timedistributed layer and having a hard time. I am trying to create a very simple model that takes a 200 x 200 rgb image and read the character written on it.

I keep getting the following error and I'm not sure how to fix it:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected time_distributed_46_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (200, 200, 3)
```

Here is my keras code:

```
num_timesteps = len(chars) # length of sequence
img_width = 200
img_height = 200
img_channels = 3

def model():
    # define CNN model
    cnn = Sequential()
    cnn.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(img_width,img_height,img_channels)))
    cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3)))
    cnn.add(Flatten())

    # define LSTM model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(TimeDistributed(cnn, input_shape=(num_timesteps, img_width,img_height,img_channels)))
    model.add(LSTM(num_timesteps))
    model.add(Dense(26))

    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

I then fit the model like so:

```
model().fit_generator(generator=images_generator(), steps_per_epoch=20, epochs=2)
```

where I generate the images like so:

```
def image_sample():
    rand_str = random_str()
    blank=Image.new("RGB", (200,200),(255,255,255))
    font = ImageFont.truetype("StatePlate.ttf", 100)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(blank)
    draw.text((30, 40),rand_str,(0,0,0), font=font)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(blank)
#     datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=90)
#     datagen.fit(blank)
    return (np.asarray(blank), one_hot_char(rand_str))

def one_hot_char(char):
    zeros = np.zeros(len(chars))
    zeros[chars.index(char)] = 1
    return zeros

def images_generator():
    yield image_sample()
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, a single image is returned by the generator. The input generated by the generator should have shape:`[batch_size, num_timesteps, img_width, img_height, img_channels]`.

A quick fix for this dummy data would be changing `np.asarray(blank)` to `np.asarray([[blank]])`.